# Valor inicial de input type file desde un FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript

Cuando intento agregar un valor inicial a un input type file desde un `FormControl` me aparece el siguiente error:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Este es el código de mi `FormGroup`:

```
this.editProduct = new FormGroup({
    'productImage' : new FormControl( '', Validators.required )
});

ngOnInit() {
    this._productsService.getProduct( this.productId )
          .subscribe( getProductData => {
    this.editProduct.controls['productImage'].setValue( 
        this.product.productImage );
    }
}
```

Form HTML:

```
<form class="animated fadeIn" [formGroup]="editProduct" 
(ngSubmit)="updateProduct()" #form="ngForm">
<input class="form-control" type="file" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid' : 
!editProduct.get( 'productImage' ).valid }" id="productImage" 
formControlName="productImage">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
    [disabled]="!form.valid">Actualizar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error es bastante explicativo: En los inputs de tipo `"file"` no puedes definir un valor inicial distinto de `""` (cadena vacía).

No es cosa de AngularJS, es que ningún navegador va a permitir que definas un path por defecto porque sería un agujero de seguridad enorme: podría crear una página maliciosa que tomase un archivo, lo abriese desde el navegador y enviara toda la información por AJAX a mi servidor