# Establecer archivo a input desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, entrada

Necesito automatizar la forma de seleccionar el archivo en un input. Agregandolo de forma manual vía JS.

Tengo esto:

```
<input type="file" id="files" onchange='stl_viewer.add_model({local_file:this.files[0]});' multiple>
```

La idea es pasar el archivo por JS y que el onchange actúe.

Alguna idea? Llevo un rato con ello y no hay manera.

Gracias!

EDITO:

Ya me han comentado que por seguridad es imposible. Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo pasar la dirección local de un archivo al formato [File Object]?

Es decir, pasar un string a este tipo de objeto, ya que el script que uso se pasa el archivo seleccionando desde el input.

¿puedo hacer algo así para que sea igual que si lo hubiera elegido desde input? this.files[0].

Gracias.

Comment: Seleccionar un archivo en un input file de manera automatizada por diseño no es posible, imagínate que esté oculto y se use para subir tus archivos a un servidor sin que lo notes.

Comment: Relacionado, (no duplicado porque la pregunta es específica de Angular) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202789/valor-inicial-de-input-type-file-desde-un-formcontrol/202793#202793

Comment: Entiendo, tiene su lógica claro. Voy a editar la pregunta. Gracias.